# How can you check for already stored variables on an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino

I have a program I want to make which will ask to see whether a variable already exists. If it does, it displays it, if it does not, it creates it and stores it in the Arduino using the PROGMEM command. Can someone explain more about PROGMEM and how to make the program I'm talking about?

Comment: You can't store data in program space (PROGMEM) during execution. This can only be used to store constant data. The data can then be read (but not written to) by the Arduino sketch using the `pgm_read_...` functions (see http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking if you are creating any variables in functions they are existing only there when function is closed all variables are deleted. If you want to keep them alive try to create global variables or use static before it;
like here

```
static int myvariable;
```

And here is answer for your question

```
 if (myvariable!=NULL)
    {
     printfucntion(myvariable);
    }
```

solution for eeprom

EEPROM Read
 Reads the value of each byte of the EEPROM and prints it to the computer.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

// start reading from the first byte (address 0) of the EEPROM
int address = 0;
byte value;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // read a byte from the current address of the EEPROM
  value = EEPROM.read(address);

  Serial.print(address);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(value, DEC);
  Serial.println();

  //move to next address of the EEPROM
  address = address + 1;

  // there are only 512 bytes of EEPROM, from 0 to 511, so if you are
  // on address 512, wrap around to address 0
  // if you have arduinoMega probably there is more eeprom space
  if (address == 512)
    address = 0;

  delay(500);
}
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: That makes sense but how can I get the program to find the variable once it is stored? Is there a way?

Comment: oo sorry now I've read Yours first post again You mean readig from eeprom of AVR look up i edit my last post

Comment: Yes, you helped a lot! Thank you very much! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just need to know how to store data into EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty stale question, and one that's not so popular. BUT is a valid question. In php, I am all the time using `isset()` to test for variables' existences. So, perhaps the OP is coming to embedded / C programming from the make-love-not-war world of php, where anything goes and isn't accustomed to the extremely literal and formal country of C.

As [pointed out here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/59173-how-check-if-variable-exists.html), C language has <kbd>#ifdef</kbd> and <kbd>#ifndef</kbd> conditional defines that are often used for the exact purpose of testing if something is defined. To better understand the nuance of this usage, one should probably visit [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=ifdef) and inquire about professional philosophy about conditional defines.

Me? I'm researching permanent variable storage on an Arduino via the EEPROM. Here are [two](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/tutorial-your-arduinos-inbuilt-eeprom/) different [excellent](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/discovering-arduinos-internal-eeprom-lifespan/) articles. And about <kbd>#ifdef</kbd>'s? I am just a lowly software engineer and save that for software architects. ;-) I have never intentionally implemented them, just see those a lot.

And a literal answer to the OP's question is: query the variable and try to use it. The Arduino's IDE compiler will scream if it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple , Just you need to Declare a variable.just compare with array of elements,you wanna compare with. If array element and enter element are present display using Serial.print() statement else you store it in array of buffer accumulating it. Display it.

As you are doing single link list

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's an old question, but given the ubiquity of the arduino, still valid. And I don't believe anyone addressed the **actual** question, which was badly worded, while references to the articles -- only one of which is still live -- give us the tools to answer. It seems to me that OP was looking for:

"If an arduino sketch runs for the first time after power-up, how can the sketch figure out if a previous session successfully saved data to the EEPROM available storage space?"

Now, the EEPROM library provides for the storage and retrieval of BYTES, not more complex data. It's up to the developer to map more complex data into bytes on read and write. So the question remains, how to KNOW that the data might be already present?

What I do is define a number of unique byte keys, each a random number between 0 and 255. These are hardcoded into the sketch. When my program converts the intended persistent data to bytes and saves them, it writes to the available storage space a sequence of byte keys before the actual data.

The next time the program runs, it reads available storage space and attempts to match the sequence of read bytes corresponding to the keys to the hardcoded keys. If the key bytes match, the sketch assumes the data has already been saved, reads it and maps it back to useful data.  If the keys are incorrect, we assume the data has NOT been saved and the user or the program must generate it again.

I'm not an expert on arduino architecture. I don't know if the data space floats in memory with respect to other storage or if it's always mapped to the same physical space. If it's always mapped to the same physical storage space, then changes to the data mapping without a corresponding change to the hardcoded keys could allow subsequent runs with revised code and mapping to try to access old data blocks, and, ah, undesirable consequences. I would suggest out of an abundance of caution that any changes to the code, and especially to the data mapping and storage/retrieval routines, should be accompanied by changes to the hard-coded keys in order to force the user to enter or define or the code to generate new data on the next run.